# Creating reciprocal dicts in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a common requirement to look up a code from value, and also a value from a code. For example, I have a dict of colours that enables me to derive  a code for the colour. On the other hand I may have a code and wish to derive the colour. I solve this by creating what I call reciprocal dicts.

```
colour_list = [["red", "0"], ["green", "1"], ["blue", "2"]]
colours = {}
codes = {}
for colour in colour_list:
    colours[colour[0]] = colour[1]
    codes[colour[1]] = colour[0]

print colours
print codes
```

If I know a code I can look up the **colour** in *codes* and if I know a colour I can look up the **code** in *colours*.

Is this the best data structure to tackle this problem? Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead.

Comment: In Clojure, this is called an *inverted map*. *Inverted dictionary* may be a Pythonic term. And what if you have duplicate values? What do you want the behavior to be?

Comment: Usually there aren't any key/value clashes in situations like this, so why not just put everything in one dict? The reciprocal items can be added with: `d.update(list(zip(d.values(), d.keys())))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead:

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour(Enum):
    red = 0
    green = 1
    blue = 2
```

You can then go both ways:

```
# getting the integer value for a name
Colour[name].value 

# getting the name for a value
Colour(value).name
```

In code, just use the members directly:

```
colour = Colour.red
```

Comment: May or may not need to consider using the `unique` decorator from the enum package if values are going to be used to access name.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: duplicate values are interpreted as *aliases*; `EnumClass(value)` will give you the first member with that value. Using either `EnumClass[first_name]` or `EnumClass[alias_name]` will also give you the first member with the value. See the [section on duplicating members and values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Very elegant. I KNEW there had to be a better way